# Google Colaboratory with GPU

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory

How long does Google Colaboratory provide GPU access for? What is their exact policy on the matter? My advisor wants me to train some models on Colab but all I could find about their GPU access was that it is provided for upto 12 hours. What exactly happens after 12 hours? How long do you have to wait to get GPU access again?

Answer (score 3):

`google colab` never really connects for up to 12 hours

because it keeps on disconnecting and this is both annoying and discouraging

Can someone fix this issue immediately and permanently

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I have experienced, it will ask you to refresh the page after 12 hours to instantiate a new session. All your data on your old instance will be lost.

Your notebook files will be in Google Drive. You need to keep the data also remote and download it to /tmp location when you run the notebook.

12 hour is the current limit. I don't see that as indefinite promise from Google based on their previous products open sourcing.

FAQ does not have any reference to any time limit. Means they can change the time limit when they can.

https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html

Hope it helps.